# System.InvalidOperationException : The asynchronous operation has not completed

Tags: c#, machine-learning, .net-core, ml.net

Fitting the pipeline causing exception in Ml.net. The `Fit` is not an awaitable and I'm confused why this happens. Any help is appreciated

`var model = pipeline.Fit(dataView);`

**Stack trace**

> at
> System.Threading.Channels.AsyncOperation.ThrowIncompleteOperationException()
> at System.Threading.Channels.AsyncOperation`1.GetResult(Int16 token)   at Microsoft.ML.Transforms.RowShufflingTransformer.Cursor.MoveNextCore()  at Microsoft.ML.Data.RootCursorBase.MoveNext()    at Microsoft.ML.Trainers.TrainingCursorBase.MoveNext()    at Microsoft.ML.Trainers.SdcaTrainerBase`3.TrainCore(IChannel ch,
> RoleMappedData data, LinearModelParameters predictor, Int32
> weightSetCount)    at
> Microsoft.ML.Trainers.StochasticTrainerBase`2.TrainModelCore(TrainContext context)    at Microsoft.ML.Trainers.TrainerEstimatorBase`2.TrainTransformer(IDataView
> trainSet, IDataView validationSet, IPredictor initPredictor)    at
> Microsoft.ML.Trainers.TrainerEstimatorBase`2.Fit(IDataView input)    at Microsoft.ML.Data.EstimatorChain`1.Fit(IDataView input)    at
> ML.DetectFakeJobPosts.Analyzer.Train() in
> D:\Sources\code-everything\CodeItHere\ML.DetectFakeJobPosts\Program.cs:line
> 75    at ML.DetectFakeJobPosts.Program.Main(String[] args) in
> D:\Sources\code-everything\CodeItHere\ML.DetectFakeJobPosts\Program.cs:line
> 13

Pipeline

```
    var pipeline = _context.Transforms.Categorical.OneHotEncoding("ec_title", "title")
        .Append(_context.Transforms.Categorical.OneHotEncoding("ec_location", "location"))
        .Append(_context.Transforms.Categorical.OneHotEncoding("ec_department", "department"))
        .Append(_context.Transforms.Categorical.OneHotEncoding("ec_salary_range", "salary_range"))
        .Append(_context.Transforms.Text.FeaturizeText("ec_company_profile", "company_profile"))
        .Append(_context.Transforms.Text.FeaturizeText("ec_description", "description"))
        .Append(_context.Transforms.Text.FeaturizeText("ec_requirements", "requirements"))
        .Append(_context.Transforms.Text.FeaturizeText("ec_benefits", "benefits"))
        .Append(_context.Transforms.Categorical.OneHotEncoding("ec_employment_type", "employment_type"))
        .Append(_context.Transforms.Categorical.OneHotEncoding("ec_required_experience", "required_experience"))
        .Append(_context.Transforms.Categorical.OneHotEncoding("ec_required_education", "required_education"))
        .Append(_context.Transforms.Categorical.OneHotEncoding("ec_industry", "industry"))
        .Append(_context.Transforms.Categorical.OneHotEncoding("ec_function", "function"))

        //drop unnecessary columns from view
        .Append(_context.Transforms.DropColumns("title", "location", "department", "salary_range", "company_profile", "description", "requirements", "benefits", "employment_type", "required_experience", "required_education", "industry", "function", "telecommuting", "has_company_logo", "has_questions"))

        //concate features
        .Append(_context.Transforms.Concatenate("Features", "ec_title", "ec_location", "ec_department", "ec_salary_range", "ec_company_profile", "ec_description", "ec_requirements", "ec_benefits", "ec_employment_type", "ec_required_experience", "ec_required_education", "ec_industry", "ec_function"))
        //set label/prediction column
        .Append(_context.Transforms.Conversion.ConvertType("Label", "fraudulent", DataKind.Boolean))
        //select a trainer
        .Append(_context.BinaryClassification.Trainers.SdcaLogisticRegression());
```

[click here for dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/shivamb/real-or-fake-fake-jobposting-prediction)

**Versions**

> Ml.net : 1.5.1
>
> Core   : 3.1

Comment: Can you share what your pipeline code looks like?

Comment: @Jon added pipeline

Comment: Thanks! Can you also show how you got your data view? Is it just loading from a file?

Comment: Yes. loading from this csv directly(https://www.kaggle.com/shivamb/real-or-fake-fake-jobposting-prediction)

Comment: Thanks! It seems like it's an error I may have introduced. I've added an [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/issues/5312) to the repo and will work on a fix.

Comment: Just put in a fix for this. Can you use [this NuGet feed](https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/dnceng/public/_packaging/MachineLearning/nuget/v3/index.json) to get the latest daily build and try your pipeline again?

Comment: @Jon I tried the given package source and re installed v1.5.1. But the issue still persists

Comment: It should be a preview version of 1.5.2. Try selecting only the new feed and check the pre-release option.

Comment: @Jon it worked with version `1.5.2-29129-1`.

Comment: Awesome! Not sure when the 1.5.2 version is planning to go out but hopefully that can help get you going further.

Comment: If you can write why this happened as an answer, others can also benefit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue for this is from a [PR I made](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/pull/5123) to update part of the code to use [Channels](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Threading.Channels). It turns out that it's not always guaranteed to finish the async call before we check the result of it which is causing the error.

There's a fix for this currently in the [daily NuGet feed](https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/dnceng/public/_packaging/MachineLearning/nuget/v3/index.json) to get the latest daily build until the 1.5.2 version gets officially released.

Comment: Just a note that version 1.5.2 of ML.NET is now released which has this fix.